# Docker-machine in wsl2

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

After connection of Docker desktop to WSL2, I've tried to install docker-machine like described [here](https://docs.docker.com/machine/install-machine/).

It is installed, but I can't get access to it via `docker-machine` command, only `docker-machine.exe` works.

When I try to create a machine with it, like [here](https://sladkovm.github.io/webdev/2017/10/16/Deploying-Plotly-Dash-in-a-Docker-Container-on-Digitital-Ocean.html)

```
docker-machine.exe create --driver "virtualbox" dash_app
```

I get this error

```
Driver "virtualbox" not found. Do you have the plugin binary "docker-machine.exe" accessible in your PATH?
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Note that if you just want Docker, you do not need docker-machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the way described for Linux, not for Windows.

```
base=https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.16.0 &&
  curl -L $base/docker-machine-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m) >/tmp/docker-machine &&
  sudo mv /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine &&
  chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```